# Python. Как в db найти 10 наиболее часто встречающихся ip-адресов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть архив с логами `access_log.db`

В этой таблице записи по посещениям веб-ресурса за несколько месяцев.
Ресурс посещают как люди, так и роботы.

Описание объектов базы:

```py
# File: db.py

from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class LogEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "logs"
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ip_addr = Column(String(16))
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, ip_addr, timestamp):
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        return "'%s' on %s" % (self.ip_addr, self.timestamp)
```

И есть задача - найти сколько запросов в базе с адреса 109.234.35.42?

Answer (score 1):

**server.py**

```
@route("/api/getIP")
def getIP():
    result = s.query(LogEntry).filter(LogEntry.ip_addr == '109.234.35.42').all()
    print(len(result))
    return "Ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

Формируем выборку по условию и счетаем кол-во записей

```
result = LogEntry.query.filter_by(ip_addr='109.234.35.42').all()
print(len(result))
```

Comment: а как это в консоли вывести? ведь это  нужно открыть  access_log.db

Comment: это sqLite база? если да, скиньте файл, я напишу весь скрипт

Comment: @ HackerU репозиторий https://clck.ru/MiCki

Comment: Боже... Ну есть же груп бай и каунт

Comment: есть, который совершенно не эфективен при этой задаче. Есть понятие оптимизации запроса, и его желательно не игнорировать )

Comment: @HackerU, вы считаете, что читать отфильтрованные данные из БД только для того , чтобы посчитать число записей в Python выгоднее чем сделать “select count(*) from ... where...” ?? А если в таблице соответствующих записей больше чем может уместиться в память машины где запускается скрипт?

Comment: @MaxU сделать count, хорошая идея, но если прочитать вопрос внимательнее, то можно понять, что здесь используется ORM. Так конечно самым простым методом было бы воспользоваться sqlite3 и сделать count. 

Однако если ваш комментарий имеет отсылку на мой ответ ERI, то можно понять, что там речь идет о группировке, что является избыточно сложным для системы.

А так вообще слишком много если)

Comment: через ORM можно точно также сделать query.count(). И @eri говорил о вопросе из заголовка вопроса - как найти топ 10 IP - для этого эффективнее всего воспользоваться группировкой